# Setup Azure Push Notification Hubs unlimit device expiry

Tags: c#, azure, azure-notificationhub, azure-sdk-.net

In order to setup unlimit device token expiry for old PNS subscription, I followed [the forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c9a1716-84dc-40b1-b956-2638aaa72cc5/registration-expiry-date?forum=notification) and [official blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/push-notification-hub-telemetry-expiry-update/).

```
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://some-notification.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=Rfu98wpnj4gBo78tPWiI=");
NotificationHubDescription hub = namespaceManager.GetNotificationHub("push");
hub.RegistrationTtl = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
namespaceManager.UpdateNotificationHub(hub);
```

It gives below error;

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Registration Ttl must be at most 90.00:00:00
>
> Parameter name: value
>
> Actual value was 10675199.02:48:05.4775807.

The classic portal still shows **Registrations Time to Live: 90 days.**

The Azure Notification Hubs nuget package version is `2.16.0.234` the newest. The blog post does not mention this result. How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with Notification Hub SDK from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs

Thanks,

Sateesh

Comment: I did, and it shows same. Possible bug in internal Azure?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you're using the package Microsoft.ServiceBus

```
using Microsoft.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Notifications;
```

Let's install package "Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs" and replace the two lines above with

```
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;
```

Then you can update **RegistrationTtl** for the notification hub.

Good luck!